# One way to get debug information from test environment c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If an application gets deadlock in our test environment I don't have a really good way to get information about the client state. For example if there is a deadlock I have no real exception or stack trace to follow.

I've tried to look around but I cant really find what the actual "standard" way of approaching this is.

What should I be looking for? Dump the client memory state to file? Or maybe remote debugging? In worst case maybe even install VS on the client and debug that way ?

How do people usually solve this problem?

Comment: Remote debugging works best for me. It makes it similar to as if its just running on your pc. If you can RDP into the client machine, and then build your solution on your PC, copy the output to the client location, then attach remote debugger while you go through steps on the client RDP, you should be able to catch exceptions, or run traces (depending on your VS version).

Comment: Usually, you would work to localize and isolate the specific scenario. Then, depending on the situation - enable full logging (i assume your app has logging with time stamps), deploy pdb symbols and use historical debugging, maybe use remote debugging

Comment: @Zack you're really lucky to work in an environment where that is possible :) RDP to the client.. WOW!

Comment: This is in our test environment so I guess RDP should work ( ? ) reading zaitsmans reply is makes this look like a really good option if doable...